# Cocos2d problems, after a few scene changes, touches on sprites at screen edge not working

Tags: memory, cocos2d-iphone, sprite, touches

My game app is nearly finished, but i still have to overcome a strange problem.

The game is about touching sprites, when touched they rotate.
But after a few scene changes or in other word, level chances, the sprites on the border of the iphone screen are difficult to touch. i have monitored the touches. the touches are not even registered by the method:

-(void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

When i touch beside the sprite the touch is registered. I suspect that it has something to do with releasing previous scenes or releasing sprite-arrays or maybe deallocing the sprites...

I just don’t now how to handle this yet, and how to neatly switch from the level selector scene back and forward to the play-field scene.

Maybe someone else reading this forum had the same problem and has solved it.

ideas and suggestions are very appreciated.

Btw: in the credits scene of my first game i will mention the stackoverflow.com site and its members for their help, it's a great forum.

Thanks guys, i am nearly there!

As Steve Jobs would say: O, there is one more thing . . .

----------------------------- update ---------------------------

Hi,

Here is an update,
I started to release the Array's in the onexit method, but that brings no joy.
Every release call results in a crash, probably arc releases them before i do.

Something that seems to help and shift the problem a few levels further down the road is the fact that i am releasing sprites, direct after they were added to the sprite array.
It looks to me that i am on the right track, but still the problems comes back after a while.

Johan

---------------------------- second update --------------------------

Hi,

The previous update that suggest that the problem would become less is not right.
The game is still suffering with the touch problem. 
I narrowed it down to the scoreboard-scene and the play-level scene change. The scoreboard scene is probably the problem maker, but where? 
I only use 4 sprites here, and some moving actions, which will come up when some parts off the score is beter than before.
The scoreboard scene is using timer methods, but i invalidate and "nil" them on the onexit method.

I am still very puzzled.

Johan

------------------------- update 3 -----------------------------

Oke SO is not a forum,
But i must say it's a great portal to post problems concering programming.

In this case i cannot reveal all the code, which would be part of this problem, I guess it would show too much intellectual information about this game, i am very sorry for that.

i am interested to see if someone else reading this SO site had the same problem and found a solution for it. I would be very greatfull when one of them would give me some guidelines to solve the touch issues.

I am very sorry for misunderstanding the SO site, but still i am hoping for an answer from one of the SO visitors.

Meanwhile, i am trying to solve the problem myself. If i find the solution before someone else gives me some help, i will post the solution to help other SO-visitors.

-------------------------FOUND THE SOLUTION FOR THIS PROBLEM --------------------------------------

As mentioned earlier, this is my first app. Probably like other beginners, sometimes we experience weird problems. Scratching the head does not help. I had a few problems before which were solved, one with help from stackoverflow.com. But it was not as weird as this touch problem. The app also sovered from instability, not mentoined earlier in this text.

Below you find the solution for both problems, touches and instability. I make a confession here, it was a beginner fault. I had fired NStimers and schedulers in the app, when the level was finished i switched to another scene WITHOUT Unscheduling the related scheduler. STUPID ME!!! I discovered a weird behaviour when the log showed me somethimes more than 45 calls to the same init of the scoreboard scene, what the f**k?

So, i changed the call from the one scene to the other scene, killed the schedulers and timers and WHOLA! The touch problem is solved as well as the stability is back again.

What can you expect when a init or whole scene is called 50 times in a second!!!! It's a time bomb with a very short fuse!

So, here is to all the other object C++ starters, but probably you already know this, but anyway i cannot hold it to my self anymore: "THINK AHEAD WHEN YOU WORK WITH SCHEDULERS AND TIMERS!!!"

I have learned my lesson.

Now i am back on the track and hopefully will finish te App soon!

Greetings,

Johan

Comment: SO is not a "forum", read the FAQ, specifically don't ask for opinions (ideas, suggestions usually fall in this category). Be concise, explain the problem, provide relevant code (very important), explain what you tried and observed, ask a specific question. Without code, it's like describing a photo to us in words - it's neither efficient nor accurate.

Answer (score 0):

-------------------------FOUND THE SOLUTION FOR THIS PROBLEM --------------------------------------

As mentioned earlier, this is my first app. Probably like other beginners, sometimes we experience weird problems. Scratching the head does not help. 
I had a few problems before which were solved, one with help from stackoverflow.com.
But it was not as weird as this touch problem. The app also sovered from instability, not mentoined earlier in this text.

Below you find the solution for both problems, touches and instability. I make a confession here, it was a beginner fault.
I had fired NStimers and schedulers in the app, when the level was finished i switched to another scene WITHOUT Unscheduling the related scheduler. STUPID ME!!!
I discovered a weird behaviour when the log showed me somethimes more than 45 calls to the same init of the scoreboard scene, what the f**k?

So, i changed the call from the one scene to the other scene, killed the schedulers and timers and WHOLA! The touch problem is solved as well as the stability is back again.

What can you expect when a init or whole scene is called 50 times in a second!!!! It's a time bomb with a very short fuse!

So, here is to all the other object C++ starters, but probably you already know this, but anyway i cannot hold it to my self anymore: "THINK AHEAD WHEN YOU WORK WITH SCHEDULERS AND TIMERS!!!"

I have learned my lesson.

Now i am back on the track and hopefully will finish te App soon!

Greetings,

Johan